# Requirements.txt not installed in Docker container

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, pip, dockerfile

I have got the following Dockerfile

```
FROM jupyter/scipy-notebook

COPY . ./work

COPY setup.py /work

RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install -e .

RUN pip install -r ./work/requirements.txt

COPY src /work/src

WORKDIR /work
```

and the following `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.7'

networks:
  ling172:

services:
   jupyter:
      
      image: jupyter/datascience-notebook:r-4.0.3
      environment:
        - JUPYTER_TOKEN=password
        - JUPYTER_ENABLE_LAB=yes

      volumes:
        - .:/home/jovyan/work
        - ./notebooks:/home/jovyan/work
        - ./src:/home/jovyan/work
      ports:
        - 7777:8888
      container_name: almond_analysis
      networks:
        - ling172
```

and the following requirements.txt file

```
openpyxl==3.0.10
```

The project structure is

```
almond_analysis:
    notebooks:
        data_exploration.ipynb
    src:
       __init__.py
       plots.py
    .gitignore
    docker-compose.yml
    Dockerfile
    README.md
    requirements.txt
    setup.py
```

and the setup file is

```
from setuptools import find_packages, setup
import sys
import os

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath( os.path.dirname(__file__)))


requirements_path="requirements.txt"
with open(requirements_path) as requirements_file:
    requirements = requirements_file.read().splitlines()

setup(
    name="almond_analysis",
    version="0.0.1",
    description = "Almond analysis",
    long_description="Analysing yield with Python.",
    author= "George N",
    packages= find_packages(),
    install_requires=requirements,
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3"
    ],
    python_requires =">= 3.0.*",
)
```

The problem is that once I open the `data_exploration.ipynb` notebook the `openpyxl` package has not been installed, which means that the `requirements.txt` file has not been read. I suspect that this is because I am starting the container with the command  `docker compose up -d` which means that I am not rebuilding the image, which means that the Dockerfile is not read. So I modified the docker-compose.yml file as follows (ie I added `build: .`)

```
version: '3.7'

networks:
  ling172:

services:
   jupyter:
      build: .
      image: jupyter/datascience-notebook:r-4.0.3
      environment:
        - JUPYTER_TOKEN=password
        - JUPYTER_ENABLE_LAB=yes

      volumes:
        - .:/home/jovyan/work
        - ./notebooks:/home/jovyan/work
        - ./src:/home/jovyan/work
      ports:
        - 7777:8888
      container_name: almond_analysis
      networks:
        - ling172
```

but without luck.

Does anyone know how to install, successfully, the packages in `requirements.txt`?

Comment: Without looking at anything else, I notice that the first two `COPY` commands in your `Dockerfile` are referencing different directories: The first one targets `./work` (a directory named `work` that is a subdirectory of whatever the current directory is), and the second targets `/work` (a directory named work that is at the root of the filesystem). That by itself could be causing some confusion, depending on what `WORKDIR` is at the beginning of your `Dockerfile`.

Comment: Have you added the `--build` parameter when starting the containers?
What does the command output when running?

Comment: @dallyger Would the command you propose be `docker compose up --build`?

Comment: Yes that would work. But you've used `-d` previously, so I would add it too. Otherwise, the docker stack is not detached, and your terminal is blocked.

So it would be `docker-compose up -d --build`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by typing `docker-compose up -d --build` with the second `docker-compose.yml` file and all other files as shown in the question (as suggested by @dallyger).